# Script error when signing into azure from visual studio 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015

When trying to connect my microsoft account to Azure from visual studio I get a script error after entering my login details:

```
An error has occurred in the script on this page.
Line: 0
Char: 0
Error: Script Error
Code: 0
URL:  https://secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com/ests/2.1.4614.5/content/cdnbundles/aad.login.min.js
```

The control is then blank and I cannot add my account to visual studio - so I can't deploy or use anything on Azure.

I've tried resetting the IE cache, resetting the dev environment, resetting IE settings. I've tried connecting 2 accounts on 2 different computers both running visual studio 2015 with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is something to do with my satellite nbn (skymuster) connection - switching to a mobile broadband connection resolved the issue.